# update mysql with javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to update my mysql table with the name of the winner in a simple raffle. the raffle works great, but I have been unable to get the name of the winner to update once is picked.

index.php

```
<?php include_once('connect.php'); //connect db ?>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Raffle drawing</title>
<meta name="Author" content="Kyle Banerjee" />
<meta name="keywords" content="raffle drawing prizes" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<link title="new" rel="stylesheet" href="includes/default.css" TYPE="text/css" />
<script language='javascript' src="includes/raffle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <div><h1>And the winner is</h1></div>
</center>
<p />
<center>
<table><tr><td>
<div id='results'>

</div>
</td></tr></table>
<div id="show">
<a class="blue" onClick="hideNames(); return false;">Hide names in box</a>
</div>
<p />&nbsp;<p />
</center>
</h1>
    <center><form name="f" onSubmit="processForm(document.f); return false;">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Find the Winner!"><p />
<div id="names">
<textarea name="userinput" style="display:none" rows="50" cols="50">
<?php 
$query = "select * from member where status=0"; 

$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo  $row['name'] . "\n" ;

  }

?>
</textarea>

    </div>
    </form></center>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var milisec=0;
var seconds=0;
var minutes=0;
var winner = '';
var contestants=[];

function processForm(obj_f) {
    seconds = 70;
    contestants = obj_f.userinput.value.split("\n");
    findWinner();
}
function winnerIs() {
                document.getElementById('results').innerHTML='<p /><winner>' + contestants[Math.floor(Math.random()*contestants.length)] + '</winner>';
                //savedata();
}

function findWinner(){
 var x=0;
 if (milisec<=0){
    milisec=9
    seconds-=1
    }
 if (seconds<=-1){
    milisec=0
    }

    if(seconds <= 0){
            clearTimeout();
            // keep trying if a black line is retrieved. Give up after 100 tries;
            winner = contestants[Math.floor(Math.random()*contestants.length)];
            while (winner.length < 2) {
                winner = contestants[Math.floor(Math.random()*contestants.length)];
                x++;
                if (x > 100) {break;}
            }
                document.getElementById('results').innerHTML='<div id="final"><winner>' + winner + '!</winner></div>';
        } else {
            winnerIs();
      setTimeout("findWinner()",10) 
        milisec-=1
      }
}

function hideNames() {
                document.getElementById('names').style.visibility='hidden';
                document.getElementById('show').innerHTML='<a class="blue" onClick="showNames(); return false;">Show names in box</a>';
}

function showNames() {
                document.getElementById('names').style.visibility='visible';
                document.getElementById('show').innerHTML='<a class="blue" onClick="hideNames(); return false;">Hide names in box</a>';
}
 function savedata() {
 }
```

any ideas on how I can get it to update to db set status=1 where name = winner??

Comment: you may have to look into `ajax` if you are not wanting page reloads.

Comment: The current approach is wrong. You are picking the winner in the client side, that means any users will also be able to pick himself as the winner!

Comment: You should use mysqli_* functions. mysql_* is deprecated php extension and is removed in php 7